# Angular-translate and ngRoute $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ngroute, angular-translate

I´m using angular-translate to add suport for 3 languages (english, portuguese and spanish) and everything is working fine.

```
    // config angular translate
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  // configures staticFilesLoader
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'translations/locale-',
    suffix: '.json'
  });

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

this way I have 3 files with all the translations for the 3 languages. But the problem that I am facing now is,

What if I need to translate data that comes from a json file and changes dynamically via $routeParams with ngRoute?

here is how I´ve done before getting into i18n

```
// MyController

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams,  $http) {
        $http.get('someFolder/' + $routeParams.itemId + '.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.item = data;
        });
    }]);
```

One of the json files

```
{
  "id": "blue",
  "color": "Blue",
  "description": "The color blue is one of trust, honesty and loyalty"
 }
```

I have a folder with json files that its loaded with the ID of the item. and my html looks like this:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-controller="MyController">
    <dt>{{ 'item.label.color' | translate }}</dt>
    <dd>{{ item.color }}</dd>
    <dt>{{ 'item.label.description' | translate }}</dt>
    <dd>{{ item.description }}</dd>
</dl>
```

I was able to translate the label of the items because its always the same across all the json files but what I actually need is to translate the values.

Is there any solution for this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the static files loader, take a look at the PartialLoader. This allows you to break your templates in to parts, and request each part individually.

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: '{part}/i18n/{lang}.json',
    loadFailureHandler: 'TranslationErrorHandler'
});
```

with this, you do

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('common');
```

that will load 'common/i18n/.json'

Comment: thanks will take a look into that. will come back to let you know if worked

Comment: I couldnt solve the problem with the PartialLoader. I couldnt find a good documentation on it. Is it possible to use two kinds of loader? because the app is already done with the static files loader and would be great if can use the PartialLoader just on that controller that get the json files with http

Comment: thanks for your response but since I´m new to angularjs (and programming actually) i created static html files instead of loading the json data dynamically with http, that way i easly translated with the static files loader. I know it changes how the app works but i dont feel confortable (yet) dealing with complex applications. thanks for your awnser though, maybe on a future project I may use that loader